# Application/program nudity filtering nudity

Tags: halal-haram, hijab, zina

Is there any application/program available that filter any nudity on the screen (computer/phone...)?

This is should certainly be possible with all the progress in image recognition. Most applications and programs that filter inappropriate images around won't filter some degree of nudity, considering them fine for the general audience among which many are still unacceptable in Islam. It will be nice to have such a program to protect our eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is not that easy even with the progress in technologies, because a lot of time this inappropriate content comes from ads which means that a company pays a website or mobile app to display there content, for publicity/marketing purposes, and when I say pay I mean some real money on the table, so those companies and websites do their best to deliver that content to the users (us), so no matter how much some programmers try to filter this content, there is more effort put to overcome those filtering programs.